# highcharts is not working in django

Tags: javascript, django, highcharts

I write an small piece of javascript code to display a barchart in django framework using highcharts. 
**my home.html contains**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block main_content %}
{% load staticfiles %}

<script src="{% static "js/day_of_week.js" %}"></script>

<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="btn_day_of_week">Day of week</button>

<div id = "container">
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

**static/js/day_of_week.js contains**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('#btn_day_of_week').click(function(){

            //alert("day_of_week is clicked");

            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Call Patterns in Week of Day'
                },

                xAxis: {
                    categories: [
                        'Sunday',
                        'Monday',
                        'Tuesday',
                        'Wednesday',
                        'Thursady',
                        'Friday',
                        'Saturday',
                    ]
                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: 'call duration(sec)'
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
                    pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                        '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
                    footerFormat: '</table>',
                    shared: true,
                    useHTML: true
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    column: {
                        pointPadding: 0.2,
                        borderWidth: 0
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Tokyo',
                    data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6]

                }, {
                    name: 'New York',
                    data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0]

                }, {
                    name: 'London',
                    data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0

                }, {
                    name: 'Berlin',
                    data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4]

                }]
            });


       });

     });
```

The `alert("day_of_week is clicked");` is working well but the graph is not displaying. How to make it display ?

Comment: can you see any error in console?

Comment: there is no error in console

Comment: do you have any CSS for `#container`? If not could you change it to: `<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>`?

Comment: I changed it but not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two errors in your code:

- `data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0` <-- missing `]`
- `'Saturday',` <-- trailling comma

After fixing this two small bugs, it works like a charm: http://jsfiddle.net/Yrygy/50/